# Magento2: How to get Grand total and Shipping total in Minicart

Tags: magento2, mini-cart, grand-total, shipping-charges

Show `grand_total` and `ShippingTotal` in **mini-cart** without creating or using any **module**.

Answer (score 0):

in "window.checkoutConfig" (Js Object) contains all information, you can select the desired html file, make html structure, and through the data-bind attribute call the method from the js-file.